# How to use I2C drivers from userspace

Tags: linux-device-driver

I have an i2c chip driver as part of linux kernel. I can verify the i2c chip driver is in the kernel from kernel boot messages. My question, should such i2c chip driver will be accessed through sysfs and if yes then how. Wouldn't my user space program will be highly dependent on one particular drive

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes as file to the `sysfs` entry and write methods to have read/write access.

```
        1. create attributes using `DEVICE_ATTR`. It is a preprocessor derivative.
        2. After creating the attributes create files in the same name which you gave while creating attributes.
   Once done, you can access your i2c driver.
```

Refer this material for further reference: given very clear 
http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/mochel/doc/papers/ols-2005/mochel.pdf